# What is the difference between registerContentObserver, registerDatasetObserver

Tags: android, cursor

What is the difference between these two notifiers?  In other words, what is the difference between "backing content" and "dataset"?

The only assumption that seems reasonable to me is that "dataset" refers specifically to the rows queried and a notification will occur if an insertion, deletion, or update is made via the existing cursor to those rows.  Whereas, backing content would reflect any committed changes to the actual database.

Is this correct?

Comment: I would be more than happy to read the documentation... if I could find it.  The documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#registerContentObserver(android.database.ContentObserver) isn't sufficient.  If you happen to know where some proper documentation is, please tell me!